# how to avoid subquery in same table

Tags: sql

Assume we have a Person table with FirstName, LastName, and some other columns.

```
FirstName | LastName | City
----------------------------
John      |    White  |   NY
Adam      |    White   |  SFO
Kevin     |    White  |   LA
Tom       |    Loni   |   Chicago
```

Now, I want to retrieve all the persons that has the same last name as "Adam", which is my input.
I don't want subqueries, meaning I don't want to select the last name of "Adam" first, and then use the result to select again. Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Subqueries are going to be most efficient, simple, and manageable. Is there some reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: You don't want to use subqueries? You would have to query the database once to find out Adam's last name is `White` if you're only searching for `Adam` as input.

Comment: Do mean, rather than avoiding subqueries, you want to avoid multiple statements?

Comment: @DigitalChris are you saying subqueries will be more efficient than Etienne Faucher's join solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a self-`JOIN` on the `LastName` field:

```
Select  P2.*
From    Person  P
Join    Person  P2  On  P2.LastName = P.LastName
Where   P.FirstName = 'Adam';
```

Comment: I was too late for mere seconds!

Comment: Thank you very much, it feels like a 1+1 question for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
select P2.* 
from Person P1
inner join Person P2 on P2.lastname = P1.LastName and P1.FirstName = 'adam'
```